# What is a widget like Intellisense for wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Here is an image of what I am looking for

[image]

The best i have found is a popup box.

It would be good if the widget was intended to be used in TextBoxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a text control that has autocomplete. You should take a look at this wxPython wiki recipe:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/TextCtrlAutoComplete

That should get you started.